# I want to PHP include a variable, doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php

I am trying to PHP include a variable from the database that contains a URL but it doesn't seem to be liking it, any ideas?

The code is

```
<?php 
$location=$row_info['location'];

include '.$location./index.php'; ?>
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: `var_dump('.$location./index.php');`

Comment: Does your directory name start and ent in fullstops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have that a bit backwards...

```
$location = $row_info['location'].'/index.php';
include $location;
```

This should work or you could use double-quotes for values and get same results.  As stated above. :)~

Comment: ¿ What ? string appends are simple and can be done anywhere?  You put a bunch of ....?  For what reason?

Comment: `@location` <--- what's this?

Comment: I think the question was about the usage of '@'. What you're saying doesn't sound like anything PHP would do.

Comment: The `@` symbol is used to suppress errors in PHP. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: I am aware of that aam1r (thank you) I have updated the post to reflect.  I was quickly, just trying to answer the question...Unfortunately, I mistyped my var declaration.  Sorry about that.

Comment: though, honestly I'd say to build a extended class handler to deal with pages and includes.  Rather, than building includes per page.  :)~  But, hey that's me.

Answer (score 3):

```
include '.$location./index.php'; ?>
```

should be

```
include ".$location./index.php"; ?>
```

Variable names are not expanded inside single-quotes. From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that
>   variable names will be expanded

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
include "$location/index.php"; ?>
```

Or this:

```
include $location.'/index.php'; ?>
```

Either of those should work better. PHP won't actually expand the $variable inside a '' quote, you'll just get $variable as text in the output instead so you want to put the $variable outside the quote using dot between them like the second example or use "" quotes like the first.

Comment: Thank you Leonick...I unfortunately, wrote the @ instead of the correct variable declaration for php $ :)  You put that together quite eloquently and it is much preferred.  Great Post.